# How to scan until the the next line is equal to 0 in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that takes a K number of coordinates and for each coordinate print "X = ___, Y = ____". So this means that the output has K lines of such format.

The program should stop when it reaches a line containing only the number "0", which is what I am struggling to implement. This is my code:

```
    public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    String kString = scanner.next();
    if (!kString.equals("0")){

        int K = Integer.parseInt(kString);
            int [] xCords = new int [K];
            int [] yCords = new int [K];
            for (int i=0; i<K; i++){
                xCords[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                yCords[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println ("X = "+xCords[i]+", Y = "+yCords[i]);
            }

    }else{
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

If my first line is just the number 0, the program stops running.

If it's another number, it effectively lets me scan K number of coordinates, but it has a weird behavior from the second K value and so on.

If I try to stop it inputing a line equal to 0 (not as the first line), it won't stop.

Any clue of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine` instead of `next`, sinc you want to stop when you find a line containing just "0" :

```
String kString = scanner.nextLine();
while (kString != null && !kString.equals("0")){
    ... processing the current kString ...
    kString = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan the entire document with

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.equals("0")){
        //break out of loop
    }
}
```

then if the line you scan is equal to "0" you can break out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

At the end it was kind of a mixture of all your recommendations. Here's my -finally- working code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

        String kString = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!kString.equals("0")){
            int K = Integer.parseInt(kString);
            int divX = scanner.nextInt();
            int divY = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("divX = "+divX+", divY = "+divY);
                int [] xCords = new int [K];
                int [] yCords = new int [K];
                for (int i=0; i<K; i++){
                    xCords[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    yCords[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println ("X = "+xCords[i]+", Y =     "+yCords[i]);
                }
                kString  = scanner.nextLine();
        }else{
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }


}
```